# align text center with css

Tags: css, position, center

I've got question related to center the page using div#container
Typically the container code is like this:

```
div#container
{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 50em;
}
```

The container div tag wrap the part of the code that I would like to align center inside it.

For example we have 2 object A and object B
_object A is position Absolute
_Object B is position Relative

Both Object A and B are wrapped inside container

Problem: only object B (position relative) is align center
The object A (absolute position) is not align center

So, how to center the things that are positioned already as absolute?
Thank you for any explaination

Comment: Can you post sample HTML of what you are describing with Object A and Object B

Comment: Cannot repeat the problem described in FF3. Both inner div are centered.

Comment: centering an absolute positioned element kinda defies the whole purpose of setting it to absolute. If you have it inside a fixed width element, just set the margin-left to be (50% - element width).

Answer (score 2):

Try setting position:relative on the #container div. Position:absolute will otherwise be absolute on the window not the div.

Answer (score 0):

Use top: 50% and margin-top: -xxx(where -xxx is equal to half of the defined height in pixels) to center absolutely positioned content vertically.

Use left: 50% and margin-left: -xxx(where -xxx is equal to half of the defined width in pixels) to center absolutely positioned content horizontally.